# Replace all instances of a character in a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array like this:

```
   [[ a, b, c]
    [ d, d, e]
    [ d, f, g ]]
```

How would I go about replacing every instance of char `d` in this 2d array while keeping the shape of the array? Assuming temp is our 2d array, I tried this but it did not work:

```
for i in range(len(temp)):
        temp[i].replace('d','')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Don't be lazy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think what OP gave there is an MRE already. The attempted code didn’t run for the obvious reason, but IMHO, that’s good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `temp` as a numpy array, try update with indexing

```
temp[temp=='d'] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use slice it on a boolean index and set the value.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[ 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    [ 'd', 'd', 'e'],
    [ 'd', 'f', 'g' ]]
)

x[x=='d'] = 'z'
```